# compile error: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers, proto3

I have a gradle project with proto3 generator:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.14")
    }
}
...

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:$protoBufCoreVersion")
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protoBufCoreVersion"
    }
}
```

Also, I have config for adding generated source code to classpath:

```
   tasks.register<Jar>("sourcesJar") {
        from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
        archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
                from(components["java"])
                artifact(tasks["sourcesJar"])
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, when all source code generated from protobuf models, I can see it in a classpath and import it in unit tests. But when I'm trying to run build or manually run unit test, next error happened:

Trying to invoke builder manually in unit tests:

```
@Test
fun test() {
   Device.newBuilder() // compile error     
}
```

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class my.project.model.request.Device, unresolved supertypes: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3
    class my.project.model.request.DeviceOrBuilder, unresolved supertypes: com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.
```

Where Device - just a simple model:

```
message Device {
  string id = 1;
  Type type = 2;
  optional string manufacturer = 3;
  optional string model = 4;
  optional string software = 5;
}
```

Which generated into next java class:

```
public final class Device extends
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 implements
    // @@protoc_insertion_point(message_implements:source.request.Device)
    DeviceOrBuilder {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
...
 @java.lang.Override
  public Builder newBuilderForType() { return newBuilder(); }
  public static Builder newBuilder() {
    return DEFAULT_INSTANCE.toBuilder();
  }
```

How can I use generated models in a test?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a transitive dependency, the thing is that the required module was not exported as a JAR module in the module with tests, because there was no next dependency: `implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:$protoBufCoreVersion")`